# Detecting screen monitor Power State change in c++

Tags: winapi, events, monitor, power-state

I have a Windows message loop. I need to detect when the screen powers back up. Is there a windows message?

[detect power state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948884/detect-power-state-change) contains the C# way, I need the C++ way, using win32 API.

If there isn't a Windows message, how do I poll for screen monitor power state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Windows message [WM_POWERBROADCAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  There Windows API has a lot of support for power management.  See the section on [Windows Power Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968807%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) at MSDN for the details.

Comment: [Registering for Power Events][1] is a much better link. See the very bottom for GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON. Thx for the ptr.


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373195.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For newer windows versions (starting with windows 8) you should use GUID_CONSOLE_DISPLAY_STATE instead of GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON