# Detect what monitor a serial port is connected to in windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I've seen this question [Dectect the port in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712915/detect-identify-the-port-hdmi-other-the-monitor-is-connected-to-in-windows-7)

However, I have a slightly different issue. I have a serial port connected to one of 2 4k LG monitors. I can detect EnumDisplayMonitors, GetMonitorInfo, EnumDisplayDevices but I have no way of knowing which 1 of the 4k LG monitor my serial port is connected to. Is there a way to do this or work around this somehow? I need it to check if I should send a signal to the connected 4k LG monitor or not.

Comment: show your code...

Comment: probably I understand "serial port" differently. Give precise names of hardware

Comment: Do you mean that you have some USB to serial adapter connected to the screen?

Comment: Oh sorry, I have a com1 connected to a serial adapter connected to the screen.