# Can I get information about vga and monitor connect status?

Tags: glfw, monitor, vulkan, vga

I'd like to get Monitor-VGA (multiple monitor and multiple vga) connection's information. Can I get that information with GLFW api or other way?

I can get monitor information with glfw api. However I cannot find about graphic device and monitor's connecting status.

Can I get the status (which monitor is connected vga no.1 and which monitor is connected to vga no.2?)?

[image: I want get these information by C++]

Comment: There might be some valuable information in this question: [Detect/identify the port (HDMI, other) the monitor is connected to in Windows 7/8/10 Win32 C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31712915/387023), at least if you're on Windows.

Comment: I use windows 10 and win64, the ports are HDMI, DP, DVI. And the VGA is NVIDIA Quadro or Geforce.

Comment: Use SetupAPI to enumerate monitors. Each monitor will include property specifying parent display adapter ID. From that point you're free to establish which is no.1 and no.2 using any criteria.