# Is it possible to detect system wake up state from hibernate/sleep in a c# application?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [detect power state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948884/detect-power-state-change)

In my c# windows form application I want to reset a counter variable upon system wake up from hibernate/sleep. Is there any methods or events exists for detecting this?

Comment: Have you looked to see if the system state is exposed in the Win32 library?  You are going to have to keep track of it if it is.

Answer (score 4):

The .NET Framework provides a [PowerModeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx) event that occurs whenever there is a change in power status, such as when a user suspends or resumes the operating system.