# Execute a code completely before system sleeps

Tags: c#

I wish to execute a piece of code in `C#` which updates a record in `database` before the `system sleep` happens.

I have tried finding it on `Pinvoke` but was not able to find it. Searching for Delay Sleep returns me the results for `Thread.Sleep` method.

Please help.

Comment: you mean you have a application running and when the user chooses to put windows to sleep your application should execute that function?

Comment: @Vajura, yes I have an application running and user chooses to Sleep the machine. I want to update a small record before he goes to the sleep mode.

Comment: That looks interesting :)

Comment: @NikhilChavan actually yes. It is a very peculiar condition where we have to update something before the sleep operation happens.

Comment: Maybe this one could help [Detect Power State Change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948884/detect-power-state-change)

Comment: @MarkusSafar, I tried that. It actually just notifies that the system got a suspend event. If I try to do a small Thread.Sleep over there to simulate my database call, the system goes to sleep even before I complete the sleep call.

Comment: Hm... I see. Actually when implementing a windows service there is the possiblity of requesting additional time, I have no idea if this helps you in any way [ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as you are not implementing a windows service.

Comment: @MarkusSafar Sadly, my answer is no. I cannot implement a Service for that. Its just a windows application.

Comment: Try doing an actual database I/O instead of Thread.Sleep. But you may wind up implementing a small service instead. It's really very easy.

Comment: why not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206183/event-to-detect-system-wake-up-from-sleep-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll have to implement [ServiceBase.OnPowerEvent Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onpowerevent.aspx)

Comment: It is a simple windows application with no service involved in it.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx) event will give you this information.

Answer (score 0):

Please see **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228288/how-can-i-know-when-windows-is-going-into-out-of-sleep-or-hibernate-mode)** to check whether Windows is going into/out of `sleep` or `Hibernate` mode

Comment: I have tried it but it does not work as expected. You can check out my comment about the post in the question itself.