# Detect power state changes in modern standby

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wmi-query

I need to detect [power state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-states#sleep-state-modern-standby) changes in [Modern Standby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby?redirectedfrom=MSDN). In my specific use case, I'm trying to detect (and react) to S0 low-power (sleep) on a Microsoft Surface Pro.

So far, I have tried these methods from a plain Console Application (VS 2019):

[SystemEvents.SessionSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

[SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

[ManagementEventWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948884/detect-power-state-change).

While I can get these to work well with my laptop, I cannot seem to capture the S0 low-power event, which the Surface Pro uses, with any of these classes.

If you follow the link for the ManagementEventWatcher, I have tried that exact code, but do not even get the "EventArrived" when invoking sleep on the Surface Pro.

Any thoughts and/or pointers?

EDIT:
I guess somewhere in WMI it is possible to detect the S0 state. Perhaps some experts in WMI knows? E.g. what classname and scope to use with ManagementEventWatcher...

Answer (score -1):

start from windows 8, there is a [PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powerbase/nf-powerbase-powerregistersuspendresumenotification) API, although it's c++, guess there should be some similar api in c#

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35509319)